# Coefficient in a polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

The coefficient of $x_1^{r_1}...x_k^{r_k}$ in $(x_1 +x_2+...x_k)^n$ is ${n \choose r_1r_2\dots r_k}$.

How would I go about finding the coefficient of $x_1^{r_1}...x_k^{r_k}$ in $(x_1^2+\dots+x^2_k)^n$.

Thanks!

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{r_1}x^{r_2}\dotsm x^{r_k}$ in $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \dotsb + x_k^2$ is zero except if one of the $r$ is 2 and the rest are zero. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You seem to be missing an exponent as well as subscripts, otherwise the answer is trivially $0$ for all $(r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k)$ with the exception of an answer of $1$ for $(r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k)$ where there is a single $r_i=2$ and all other $r_j=0$.  If you are asking for the coefficient of $x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2}\dots x_k^{r_k}$ in $(x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_k^2)^n$ then make a change of variable $x_i^2=y_i$.  Then solve the same way, finding the coefficient of $y_1^{r_1/2}y_2^{r_2/2}\dots$, noting that a fractional power is impossible to obtain.

Comment: Are you missing the power of $n$ in the second line?

Comment: Yes I am ! I've fixed that, the change of variable was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

That's easy : substitute your $x^2_i,\,i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ like this :
$$ \forall 1\leqslant i\leqslant k : x^2_i=y_i $$
Then :
$$ [y_1^{\nu_1}y_2^{\nu_2}\dots y_k^{\nu_k}](y_1+y_2+\dots+y_k)^n = {n \choose {\nu_1,\nu_2,\dots,\nu_k}}, $$
where $[m^2](1-m)^3$ is the coefficient of $m$ in the development of $(1-m)^3$ (that is : $-3$), and $\sum_1^k \nu_i = n$.

Substitute back, and the coefficient of $x_1^{r_1}\dots x_k^{r_k}$ in the expansion of your polynomial is :

$$[x_1^{r_1}x_2^{r_2}\dots x_k^{r_k}](x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_k^2)^n = {n \choose {\nu_1,\nu_2,\dots,\nu_k}},$$
where, for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, we have : $r_i=2\nu_i$